Why std::pair as value in std::unordered_map with boost::container::pmr::polymorphic_allocator fails to compile
Background
In some mutiplatform project polymorphic allocator has been used to optimize use of memory.
It give nice performance boost.
Now everything has worked great until testing was done on older version of MacOS (which project supports).
Problem is the std::pmr::memory_resource requires MacOS 14 and project supports: MacOS 10.14
C++ Language Support - Xcode - Apple Developer




Feature
Paper
Notes




Features implemented in the libc++library <memory_resource>




<memory_resource>
P0220R1
Requires Xcode 15 Minimum deployment target: iOS 17.0, macOS 14.0, watchOS 10.0 and tvOS 17.0.




So to overcome this problem I've decided, to replace some parts with respective boost versions.
Problem
Change seemed simple, but got strange compilation issue. Here is MCVE:
#include <boost/container/pmr/global_resource.hpp>
#include <boost/container/pmr/memory_resource.hpp>
#include <boost/container/pmr/monotonic_buffer_resource.hpp>
#include <boost/container/pmr/polymorphic_allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/container/pmr/resource_adaptor.hpp>
#include <boost/container_hash/hash.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace foo {
using namespace boost::container::pmr;

template <typename T = std::byte>
using allocator = boost::container::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<T>;

template <class Key, class T, class Hash = std::hash<Key>, class KeyEqual = std::equal_to<Key>>
using unordered_map = std::unordered_map<Key, T, Hash, KeyEqual, foo::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>>;

using wstring = std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, allocator<wchar_t>>;
}

using Key = char;

struct Buz {
    Key key;
    foo::wstring s;
};

#ifndef USE_PAIR
using Value = Buz;
#else
using Value = std::pair<Key, foo::wstring>;
#endif

void test(foo::unordered_map<Key, Value>& m, Key key, [[maybe_unused]] std::wstring s)
{
    m.emplace(key, Value {});
    m.try_emplace(key, Value { key, foo::wstring { s } });
}

Live demo on compiler explorer.
As you can see I've fixed issue by introducing explicit struct Buz. This is even more confusing since std::pair and struct Buz shouldn't be so different in a behavior.
Most interesting part of error is (when using std::pair:
<source>:37:14:   required from here
   37 |     m.emplace(key, Value {});
      |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/app/boost/include/boost/container/detail/dispatch_uses_allocator.hpp:251:30: error: no matching function for call to 'dispatch_uses_allocator(boost::container::new_allocator<std::pair<const char, std::pair<char, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, boost::container::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<wchar_t> > > > >&, boost::container::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const char, std::pair<char, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, boost::container::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<wchar_t> > > >, false> >&, std::pair<char, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, boost::container::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<wchar_t> > >*, std::pair<char, std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, boost::container::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<wchar_t> > >)'
  251 |       dispatch_uses_allocator(construct_alloc, arg_alloc, dtl::addressof(p->second), ::boost::forward<V>(y));
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/app/boost/include/boost/container/detail/dispatch_uses_allocator.hpp:117:12: note: candidate: 'template<class ConstructAlloc, class ArgAlloc, class T, class ... Args> typename boost::move_detail::enable_if_and<void, boost::container::dtl::is_not_pair<T>, boost::move_detail::not_<boost::container::uses_allocator<T, typename boost::move_detail::remove_cvref<ArgAlloc>::type> > >::type boost::container::dtl::dispatch_uses_allocator(ConstructAlloc&, ArgAlloc&&, T*, Args&& ...)'
  117 |    >::type dispatch_uses_allocator
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Questions

what is the root cause of the problem? What is explanation?
how can I fix it in both places, when std::unordered_map::emplace using allocator boost::container::pmr::polymorphic_allocator so it works when invoking:  std::unordered_map::emplace and std::unordered_map::try_emplace

Notes
In original code boost was not used and then everything works.

I suppose the problem is that according to the standard, std::pair works as a uses-allocator type, even though it doesn't strictly implement the usual traits: cppreference

As a special case, std::pair is treated as a uses-allocator type even though std::uses_allocator is false for pairs (unlike e.g. std::tuple): see pair-specific overloads of std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator::construct and std::scoped_allocator_adaptor::construct (until C++20) std::uses_allocator_construction_args(since C++20).

I suspect that the special case is either not implemented in Boost, or it doesn't apply to std::pair transparently.
I suggest raising the potential issue of c++20 support with the Boost Container maintainers over at Github and perhaps mention the c++20-specific bit immediately following:

The utility functions std::make_obj_using_allocator, and std::uninitialized_construct_using_allocator may be used to explicitly create an object following the above protocol, and std::uses_allocator_construction_args can be used to prepare the argument list that matches the flavor of uses-allocator construction expected by the type.

